# How to guarantee corner cases in property based testing

Tags: testing, scalacheck, property-based-testing

Recently, I'm quite excited when reading about the idea of property based testing.

But I have 1 question that I still cannot find the answer anywhere:

**How can property based testing ensures that it will test the corner cases every time?**

To be more specific, let say I'm using [ScalaCheck](https://www.scalacheck.org/) to test my division function:

```
def divide(a: Int, b: Int): Int
```

As the test cases will be generated randomly, how can I be sure that ScalaCheck will check the case where `b = 0` every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Special cases are often properties of their own. If you try to write a single case that covers `b = any integer`, then all your properties will end up in one big and complicated test. But you can split the parameter space into multiple chunks e.g.:

- b = positive integer
- b = negative integer
- b = 0

And check them separately.

Comment: I see, so the answer is corner cases are not guaranteed so we have to handle them separately

Answer (score 2):

Some PBT tools will always inject corner cases before generating random ones.

For example, jqwik (for Java) would try 0, 1, -1, Integer.MIN…VALUE and Integer.MAX…VALUE before any random values.